# mysql query for filtering specific rows by date condition in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table '***meetings***' which has following fields

```
id   recurring_start_date  recurring_end_date (Both are date fields)
1.    2012-07-22             2012-07-25
2.    2012-07-27             2012-08-05
3.    2012-07-26             2012-08-26
4.    2012-07-23             2012-10-23
5.    2012-08-24             2012-11-24
6.    2012-09-12             2012-10-19
7.    2012-07-28             2012-07-29
```

I want to filter those rows by sql query which contain '**2012-07-28**' date between **start-end recurring dates** range and including start n end recurring date.
We know result will be 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 7th rows.
But how do i run this query in php.

I tried this, but its not working.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        `meetingss` 
    WHERE 
        `recurring_st_date` >= \'2012-07-28\' 
        AND `recurring_ed_date` <= \'2012-07-28\' 
    ";
```

May be am going wrong , may be supplied date condition wrong.
Any good suggestion my mates to do this. Thanks...

Comment: Are these date fields or varchar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `meetings` 
        WHERE date('2012-07-28') 
              between `recurring_st_date` AND `recurring_ed_date`";
```

Comment: You may need an explicit conversion of the string '2012-07-28' to date. At least it would be more portable that way.

Comment: the conversion is not necessary to make it work. But being portable is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

```
`recurring_st_date` >= STR_TO_DATE('2012-07-28', '%Y-%m-%d') AND 
`recurring_ed_date` <= STR_TO_DATE('2012-07-28', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslashes

```
`recurring_st_date` >= '2012-07-28' 
AND `recurring_ed_date` <= '2012-07-28'
```